# Agregar datos de llave foranea Laravel en el controlador

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente controlador

```
   public function store(MachineCreateRequest $request)
{

    $user_id = auth()->id();
    $company_id = User::find($user_id)->company->id; //ID = 3
    $machine->company_id = $company_id;
    $machine = Machine::create($request->all());
    $machine->company()->attach($company_id);
    $machine->accessories()->sync($request->accessories);
    $machine->developments()->sync($request->developments);
    session()->flash('success', 'Maquina creada correctamente');
    return redirect()->route('machine.index');
}
```

¿Como podria insertar en el Machine::create el campo $company_id? ya que cuando creo el registro sale un error General error: 1364 Field 'company_id' doesn't have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

**¿Como podria insertar en el Machine::create el campo $company_id?**

Necesitaría conocer un poco más el modelo de tu base de datos y las relaciones, pero de acuerdo a tu pregunta, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
public function store(MachineCreateRequest $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $company_id = $user->company['id']; //ID = 3

    // Agregar company_id al request me da a entender que existe un campo company_id en la tabla machines.
    $request->merge(['company_id' => $company_id]);
    $machine = Machine::create($request->all());

    $machine->company()->attach($company_id);
    $machine->accessories()->sync($request->accessories);
    $machine->developments()->sync($request->developments);

    session()->flash('success', 'Maquina creada correctamente');
    return redirect()->route('machine.index');
}
```